# Incrementing by User Input

Tags: java

I am trying to increment the counter by whatever number the user inputs.  I have been at this for almost an hour now and cannot figure it out.  Any ideas?

Here's what I have:

```
if (starting < ending) {
        while (i < ending) {
            ++i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    else if (starting > ending) {
        while (i > ending) {
            --i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

No matter what increment is entered, it starts at the starting number and counts up or down by 1.

Answer (score 0):

It counts up or down by 1 because of `++i` and `--i`. The `++` and `--` operators are equal to `i = i + 1` and `i = i - 1`, or `i += 1` and `i -= 1` respectively.

In order to increase or decrease by the amount a user enters, use `i = i + userInput` and `i = i - userInput`, or `i += userInput` and `i -= userInput`.

For example:

```
int userInput = 4;

if(starting < ending) {
    while(i < ending) {
        i = i + userInput;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
 // ... etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it is an infinite loop and printing out all 1.0s.

Comment: I fixed the infinite loop, but it is not honoring my starting number.

Comment: Post the code you are using to get your `starting`, `ending`, and user input values.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you could put:

```
while (i > ending){
  i -= numberUserInput;
}
```

This will reassign i's value with itself plus the variable that holds the number the user input (named whatever you want). For addition, you could use += instead of -=.